# How to override auto inline styles from Three.js on canvas element for page background?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

i have created a scene with three.js and i want to use it as the background for my page but i can't for the life of me get the canvas element to move without chopping off half of my page.

i have gotten rid of every bit of css i had so there are no potential conflicts. it seems like three.js has some auto styling happening inline on the canvas element, but i cant override it.

[devtools, only place i can see the auto styling thats being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C279E.png)

i have tried using !important for the properties i was trying to override, i've tried styling the element inline myself. and i've obviously tried everything i can think of in a separate stylesheet.
i also tried moving all of my three.js into its own file so that i could try  instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the three.js canvas through CSS alone. You need to control it through [`WebGLRenderer.setSize( width, height )`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setSize).

This is because the `renderer` needs to be able to tell the GPU the size of the render target `canvas`. Without this information, the GPU can't fit the rendered data to the output buffer, and it will cause all kinds of funky results.

Along with this, you'll want to update your camera's aspect ratio. [`PerspectiveCamera.aspect`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=perspectivecamera#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.aspect) should be set to the `width / height` of the `canvas`, followed by a call to [`PerspectiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=perspectivecamera#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.updateProjectionMatrix). For an [`OrthographicCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=ortho#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera) you'll need to adjust the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties to match the new aspect ratio, followed by a call to [`OrthographicCamera.updateProjectionMatrix()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=ortho#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera.updateProjectionMatrix).

These two steps are often placed in a resize handler. You can look at any of the three.js examples to see this done. [Here's the code from one of them](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/70cc4e192fe2ebd0bf8542a81c8c513d61984c58/examples/webgl_geometries.html#L138).